# ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotations - How to localize Display / Prompt

Tags: localization, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I'm using resource files for localizing DataAnnotations in my models. For example, this works just fine:

```
[Display(Name = "FullName", ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Localization)]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

However, I'd like to localize placeholder inside editiors. Instead of using

```
new { @placeholder = "Full name" }
```

inside EditorFor, I tried with the Promt inside Display annotation, e.g.:

```
[Display(Name = "FullName", ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Localization), Prompt = "FullName")]
```

Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work - it displays nothing. Is there a solution for localizing placeholders for editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yust for the record, I ended up with the following solution:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @placeholder = Localization.FullName })
```

Placeholder value "belongs" to view anyway, so it seems quite rigth to handle it in the view, not in the underlying model.